# WPF: Newbie animation question

Tags: wpf

When button1 is clicked I want this sequence

1. RectangeA becomes visible
2. RectangeA opacity changed from 0 to 75% over lets say 3 seconds
3. ControlB becomes visible.

Steps 1 and 3 are easy with imperative code, but I'm assuming I need to learn how to use story boards to do step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the storyboard that describes your sequence:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="animate">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="button1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="0.75"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="button1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Visibility.Visible"/>                
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="control" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="Visibility.Visible"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

You can trigger it in xaml through EventTrigger or in code through TryFindResource().
[Here is the link on Animation Overview MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) and you can find there answers on your questions on many WPF animations topics.